# AndroidStudio: Can not download JellyBean SDK (API 16)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

Android Studio 2.3.3

Here my SDK tools:

[image: SDK Tools]

Here my list of System Images:

[image: System Images]

As you can see I can not download JellyBean (API 16).

But I need it. How I can do this?

Comment: Did you try to download it from the Android SDK page first?

Comment: No. All SDKs I always download by Android Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click and drag on the divider between "Release name" and "API level" column in the second screenshot to make the first column larger and you will see the `Download` link.

I think you're also confusing the SDK with the emulator image. If you want to compile against an older SDK, in Android Studio open `Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> SDK Platforms` (tab) then select and install the required platform SDK.